# Do PostgreSQL advisory locks not work within transactions?

Tags: postgresql, locking, concurrency, npgsql

I'm using C# with the Npgsql driver to connect to postgresql 9.6.9. I have two servers connecting to the same database, running the following initialization code in a loop, to be sure they conflict with each other:

```
using (var txScope = new TransactionScope())
using (var connection = Connection())
{
    connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1024)", connection))
    using (cmd.ExecuteReader()) { }

    // The following line fails:
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_column()   
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ BEGIN RETURN NEW; END; $$ language 'plpgsql'; ", connection))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(1024)", connection))
    using (cmd.ExecuteReader()) { }

    txScope.Complete();
}
```

The advisory lock should prevent the `CREATE` query from running more than once currently, but it is consistently failing with "Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): XX000: tuple concurrently updated" where the function is created. If I use `LOCK TABLE` instead of the advisory lock, it works. If I do it without transactions, it also works. However, it seems like a fragile design to remove transactions every time I want to lock.

Note: I've tried this with the Npgsql Transactions API, and with `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` with the same result.

I think the lock is correctly working as a mutex, so what's going wrong with the transaction?

Comment: `BEGIN ... COMMIT` absolutely supports "concurrency" - if it didn't no transactions would work in Postgres .

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The 2nd sentence of these docs say it's not supported. Did the author mean to describe only his library rather than all of PostgreSQL?: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/transactions.html

Comment: Well the the sentence "does not supported nested transactions" is true. But the "does not support concurrent transactions" is only true regarding concurrent transactions started in the **same** session (=connection). Multiple sessions (=connections) can absolutely use concurrent transactions using `BEGIN ... COMMIT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you know if begin/commit/begin/commit is supported within a single connection? Because connections are pooled so that would be a necessary feature. (I had problems with `BeginTransaction()`, but I don't remember the test case.)

Comment: I don't know C# or Npgsql but Postgres can absolutely handle that (it works without problems through JDBC)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the info. The `BeginTransaction` method definitely didn't work with connection pooling, but I didn't yet try `BEGIN`/`COMMIT`.

Comment: I've never used npgsql or ado.net.  If  had to, the way I would tackle this is to set `log_statement=all` in the server, and then look in the server log file to see what was actually getting sent.

Comment: The first and last cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() are possibly inapt, as the contents of `cmd` definitely are queries.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks. Changing them to `using (cmd.ExecuteReader())` worked but did not solve the problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Just for the sake of correctness: pg_advisory_lock() creates a session level lock which is not affected by transactions in any way. Transaction level lock can be acquired using the pg_advisory_xact_lock().